# Problem with Connect-VIServer and Disconnect-VIServer on my powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, vmware, powercli

I've a problem with my powershell script and I don't know how to fix it.

My script allow to recover the VM protected by Zerto and to get each tags of these VMs on the vcenter.

My problem is on how my script works.

At the beginning, I initiate a connexion on each Vcenter because the VMs are located on two differents Vcenter. Then I can recover the information that I want for each VM.

```
#### Skip SSL/TSL verification
add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy

#### Set connexion to each Vcenters

#### Connect to XXX
Connect-VIServer -Server Vcenter1 -User My_User@my.domain -Password XXXX 
#### Connect to XXX
Connect-VIServer -Server Vcenter2 -User My_User@my.domain -Password XXXX 

[...]

#### Create post-script file with VM + Vcenter + Tags + Cluster
foreach ($VPG in $Get_VPG){

    $VM_List = $BaseURL+"vms?vpgName=$VPG"

    $VM1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $VM_List -TimeoutSec 100 -Headers $zertSessionHeader_json -ContentType $TypeJSON | ConvertTo-Json
    $VM2 = $VM1 | ConvertFrom-Json
    $VM3 = $VM2.value.VmName

    foreach($VM in $VM3){

        $Get_Tag = Get-VM $VM | Get-TagAssignment 
        
        $Get_Tag_And_VM = Get-VM -Name $VM | Select-object Name,
        @{N = 'vCenter'; E = {([system.uri]$_.ExtensionData.Client.ServiceUrl).Host}},
        @{N = 'Tags'; E = {(Get-TagAssignment -Entity $_).Tag -join ', '}},
        @{N = 'Cluster';E={Get-Cluster -VM $_}}  

        $Get_Tag_And_VM2 = $Get_Tag_And_VM | Where-Object {$_ -match 'Tags=;'}
        Add-Content $Result -Value $Get_Tag_And_VM2 
 
    }   

}

Write-Output "[+] Deconnexion Vcenter1 et Vcenter2" 
Disconnect-VIServer -Server Vcenter1 -Confirm:$false
Disconnect-VIServer -Server Vcenter2 -Confirm:$false
```

I can see that at the beginning of the script, each connexions are done :

[image]
And I can see that I can recover each informations that I need from a CSV file.

At the end, I have a two disconnect. But at this step, I've this error :

[image]

You can see that in the script, the disconnect part is **Disconnect-VIServer * -Confirm:$false**.

I have the same problem with **Disconnect-VIServer * -Confirm:$false** and with a disconnect for each Vcenter.

Are able to tell me why I've this error whereas each connexion are done well at the beginning ? And I don't know why this problem doesn't appears everytime. The problem appears occasionally.

Does anyone have an idea about this issue ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What is your output for `Get-PowerCLIConfiguration`? Are you in multiple mode?

Comment: Error says "Cannot find ... name".  Make sure the manes that script is using one of the names you  blackout.

Comment: @Scepticalist The output of the Get-PowerCLIConfiguration command is :

https://zupimages.net/up/23/05/wvw2.png

I'm not in a multiple mode.

Comment: @jdweng the name are the same.

Comment: If you're not in multiple mode, when you connect to a second VI server the first one is disconnected....

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Scepticalist. 

So I've to put Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -DefaultVIServerMode Multiple before my two connections ?

Comment: I think the issue here is that you use 2 `Connect-VIServer` without disconnecting from the first one first. Try disconnecting first from 1 and then connect to the second.